# How to add the value of arraybuffer

Tags: scala

For e.g.:

```
  val xs = List((1,ArrayBuffer(900.0, 400.0))
                (2,ArrayBuffer(2000.0, 800.0))
                (3,ArrayBuffer(1500.0, 600.0, 700.0, 1100.0)))
```

`ArrayBuffer` is growable.

How to add the values of `ArrayBuffer`?

Output should be look like:

```
 List((1, 1300.0)
      (2, 2800.0)
      (3, 3900.0))
```

How to write script in scala?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List(
  (1, ArrayBuffer(900.0, 400.0)),
  (2, ArrayBuffer(2000.0, 800.0)),
  (3, ArrayBuffer(1500.0, 600.0, 700.0, 1100.0))
).map({ case (i, xs) => (i, xs.sum) })

// res0: List[(Int, Double)] = List((1,1300.0), (2,2800.0), (3,3900.0))
```